# Turning an email address in a cell into a clickable link

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a column of email addresses and would really like to turn them into clickable links. I am a rookie coder still and trying to figure this out. So the code below is from trying to record a macro in google app script. I need it to reference the current cell, turn that cells email address into a link to it, then move down the column.

Should be super simple, take cell A1's contents, turn into link of the contents in the cell, then move down the list and do it again until it completes the entire column.

```
function emailing() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setShowHyperlink(true);
   spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=HYPERLINK("mailto:test@emailaddress.com","test@emailaddress.com")');
```

};

Each email will be turned into a link to that email address.

Comment: To be clear, are you looking for help making a macro, or making a script? How do you intend for this to function?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the following code and worked successfully converting each email to a hyperlink. Assuming you want to convert all of them when you use the macro, this code works for you:

```
 function emailing() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

    for(i=0; i<1048576; i++) {
      var gcells = sheet.getRange(6 + i, 6); //In my test i put the emails in the F column starting from the 6th row.
      var email = gcells.getValue();
      if (gcells.isBlank()) {
        break
      }
      gcells.setFormulaR1C1('=HYPERLINK("mailto:' + email + '","' + email + '")');
    } 
  }
```

I used the number 1048576 as the limit on the for because that's the maximum number of rows you can have, although it'll break when it takes a blank cell.

If what you want is to convert to a hyperlink only the cell you have selected and then change the selected cell, you should use the getActiveCell function [1] to set only that value and then the activate() function [2] to change the selection to the next cell.

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getactivecell

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#activate()

Comment: This works but when it hits a blank cell it stops completely. How do I make it so if it hits a blank cell it skips and goes to the next cell, out of the few thousand emails there are like 10 blanks in there and it stops every time.

Comment: Just remove the "break" then... and think in changing the "for" limit (1048576) to a smaller number otherwise it'll take a lot of time to run.